# IOS 10 websockets dropping

Tags: javascript, ios, websocket, safari

On IOS 10 within safari (and chrome) websocket connections are dropping, I can see it making the initial connection on the server side, but then doesn't keep it alive.

Before updating to IOS 10 everything was working correctly, it also works fine in safari on OSX.

There are also no signs of error in the JS console my initial thoughts are issues with the Content-Security-Policy but I have still come to no avail.

Comment: Power management putting things to sleep?

Comment: No the drop happens immediately after connecting

Comment: Perhaps this issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7772

Comment: Saw the exact post! I had to add that tag in order to get that initial connection, but it seems to still drop it right after connecting.